# IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud Asp.Net package

Tags: asp.net, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I would like to use IBM Watson Conversation service to build a chatbot web application in the Asp.Net platform. I installed IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud Asp.Net package today, but have no idea what I should do with it and there is no document. There are about 50 projects in the solution, which one can be used for the so called simple chatbot web application?

Answer (score 1):

**Watson Developer Cloud** has all the documentation that you need to use Watson Services, include *Conversation Service*.

Here are some [examples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/development/src/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1) to use Conversation:

**Installation**

*Nuget*

```
PM > Install-Package IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1
```

*Project.json*

```
"dependencies": {
   "IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1": "1.2.0"
}
```

*Usage*

You complete these steps to implement your application: Configure a workspace. With the easy-to-use graphical environment, you set up the dialog flow and training data for your application. Develop your application. You code your application to connect to the Conversation workspace through API calls.

*Instantiating and authenticating the service*

Before you can send requests to the service it must be instantiated and credentials must be set.

```
// create a Conversation Service instance
ConversationService _conversation = new ConversationService();

// set the credentials
_conversation.SetCredential(<username>, <password>);
```

*Send message*:

```
//  create message request
MessageRequest messageRequest0 = new MessageRequest()
{
  Input = new InputData()
  {
    Text = <input-string0>
  }
};

//  send a message to the conversation instance
var result0 = _conversation.Message(<workspace-id>, messageRequest0);

//  reference the message context to continue a conversation
messageRequest messageRequest1 = new MessageRequest()
{
  Input = new InputData()
  {
    Text = <input-string1>
  },
  Context = result.Context
};

//  Send another message including message context.
result1 = _conversation.Message(<workspace-id>, messageRequest1);
```

Obs.: In [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-watson-conversation-service-and-consume-from-net-code/) have one full guide step-by-step to use Watson Conversation Service with `.Net`.

- See the Official Documentation for [.Net SDK](https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/dotnet-standard-sdk/docs/development/html/d2/d45/namespace_i_b_m_1_1_watson_developer_cloud_1_1_conversation.html)
- One good Tutorial Video Guide to [Integrating Watson Conversation in your Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHIFYrQpqa4).
- See the [Official API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#) for use Watson Conversation Service (You can have a base with this link).